# call function until inserted line is ""

Tags: c++

I would like to know how I could stop performing a function when the input has nothing string == "".

I made the following code I am a beginner
**The bad thing is that it should not perform the operation if the input is == ""**:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
void my_function(string a)
{
    cout << "Operation performed with: " << a << "\n";
}
int main()
{
    string a = "h";
    while(a.compare("") != 0)
    {
        getline(cin, a);
        my_function(a);
    }
}
```

And I would like apart from solving the code if you could give me tips to do it in a better way, For example I saw once that they more or less did it this way:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
void my_function(string a)
{
    cout << "Operation performed with: " << a << "\n";
}
int main()
{
    string a = "h";
    while(cin >> a)
    {
        my_function(a);
    }
}
```

Running the program I have:

```
a
Operation performed with: a
d
Operation performed with: d
w
Operation performed with: w
r
Operation performed with: r
q
Operation performed with: q

Operation performed with:
```

But it should be:

```
a
Operation performed with: a
d
Operation performed with: d
w
Operation performed with: w
r
Operation performed with: r
q
Operation performed with: q
```

Comment: Remember in C++ you can compare a `std::string` like `s == ""`, there's no fancy stuff required, especially not a clunky `compare()` call. You could also check `!s.length()`.

Comment: It's also important to note that as per the documentation "when consuming whitespace-delimited input...any whitespace that follows, including a newline character, will be left on the input stream." so it won't be perfectly empty.

Comment: Add some details to be more explicit

Comment: @tadman `!s.empty()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will improve it, however I still have the problem of terminating the program without using break or return

Answer (score 0):

You want to loop as long as you read in lines that are not empty.

```
string a;
//loop as long as we...
while(std::getline(cin, a) //read in lines...
    && !a.empty()) //that are not empty
{
    my_function(a);
}
```

Comment: It stays forever in the while

Comment: @KSIER45 Ah right, "read in lines" -> `std::getline`. Fixed.

Comment: Yes, that's a good way, I'd expect to see in well written code. Well, without the comments.